# Change mnemonic modifier key in Java/Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, mnemonics

Setting focus hot keys in Swing is very easy:

```
  tfldPlantsNeeded = new JTextField( FIELD_LEN_MED );
  lblPlantsNeeded = new JLabel( "Plants Needed" );
  lblPlantsNeeded.setDisplayedMnemonic( 'p' );
  lblPlantsNeeded.setLabelFor( tfldPlantsNeeded );
```

This will give focus to the `tfldPlantsNeeded` JTextField when the user presses `ALT+p`.  It also highlights/displays the character that will trigger the focus change.  (In this case, when `ALT` is pressed, the 'P' in "Plants" is underlined.)

This is great ... well, kinda.  On a Mac, when the user presses `ALT` (which is also `Option` on the Mac keyboard) the mnemonic is highlited, but the focus change isn't triggered when `p` is pressed too.  If, however, the user presses `Control + Option + p`, then it works as "expected" and focus is changed.  (As an aside, if the user DOES press `Option + p`, the currently focused text field will get funny characters inserted.)

I know that I can do this myself by specifying custom keybindings via `getInputMap` and `getActionMap`, but **is there a way to change the application global mnemonic modifier** so that we can use the automatic keybindings and trigger character highlighting?  (In my case, I would like to use `Command` or `Meta` as  the mnemonic modifer key.)

Comment: yes (never tried) those accelator are - 1. TextAction or 2 UIManager

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this isn't as straightforward as you might think, but there is a way.

First of all, for menus (`JMenu`) there is a property which is controlled by the look and feel called `Menu.shortcutKeys`which you can set manually. This sets the mnemonic modifier for menus in the specific look and feel. If you want more information about this feel free to ask.

In order to set the mnemonic modifier for everything, you need to override the default toolkit (`Toolkit`). First of all, run a main method to find what it is with the following lines

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.awt.headless"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("awt.toolkit"));
```

If the first line is `null` of `false` (see `java.awt.Toolkit getDefaultToolkit()`) then the second line will give you the class name which is used as the default Toolkit for your system. I use Windows and the second line gives the output `sun.awt.windows.WToolkit`. Now create a class that overrides `getFocusAcceleratorKeyMask` in your default toolkit. For me it looks like this

```
public class MyToolkit extends WToolkit {

    @Override
    public int getFocusAcceleratorKeyMask() {
        return InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK;
    }
}
```

Finally, we have to tell the system to use it. In your application, put the line

```
System.setProperty("awt.toolkit", "packagename.MyToolkit");
```

where you need to set the correct package path to your class. Make sure this line is placed before starting any GUI related code, preferably in the first lines of `main`. This should now set `CONTROL` as the global mnemonic modifier (or use `META_DOWN_MASK` if that's what you want. Look at `java.awt.event.InputEvent` for MASK list.).

Comment: WToolkit is final and cannot be extended.